# Sign up request error in vscode when I try to create scratch org

Tags: scratch-org

command:sfdx force:org:create -s -f config/project-scratch-def.json -a ebikes

error : " The signup request failed because this organization has reached its daily scratch org signup limit ".
 Why is it so?. Cant I sign up anymore. How much is the sign up limit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are strict limits on the number of scratch orgs you can create per day, and how many active scratch orgs you can have. The limits depend on the type of org that is the Dev Hub.

You will need to wait until tomorrow now to get a new allocation of limits.

See "Scratch Org Allocations and Considerations" in the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_dev.meta/sfdx_dev/sfdx_dev_scratch_orgs.htm) for details.

Comment: Thanks for your answer and reference.